# How to connecct/query Azure SQL Always encrypted from Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I have a table in my azure database with 2 columns, one is `id`, the other is `value`, which is an encrypted column. Now I want to connect, write, read the table from Python. In case of a normal table, the following would be the way to connect from Python, and it works:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

But since it is a table with encrypted columns, I'm unable to write/read to it by connecting with the above command. I believe I need to pass `Trusted_connection=yes; ColumnEncryption=Enabled` when connecting, but I'm unable to do so. Help appreciated regarding the same. Thank you in advance!

Edit 1:
When I query the encrypted column, it gives me the encrypted value. How do I decrypt it and get the original value?
Also how do i insert encrypted value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it is possible!

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password';ColumnEncryption=Enabled;KeyStoreAuthentication=KeyVaultClientSecret;KeyStorePrincipalId='+client_id+';KeyStoreSecret='+client_secret)
c = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "select * from MyTable"
c.execute(sql)
print(c.fetchall())
```

To insert:

```
sql = "insert into MyTable (id, number) values (?, ?)"
values = [1, 10]
c = cnxn.cursor()
c.execute(sql, values)
c.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the encryption and decryption is done at the client side, .NET framework 4.6 or above is needed.  Version 1 of Always Encrypted only supported SQL Server Client driver but ODBC and JDBC drivers were not supported. It seems nothing have changed even for pyodbc as shown [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/133).

Comment: So its not possible using pyodbc?

Comment: I cannot find any documentation saying it is now possible.

Comment: How come the encryption is done on the client side? The keys are stored in the key vault which is not available at the client side!!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-client-development?view=sql-server-ver15 says that Always Encrypted is also supported for JDBC, ODBC and PHP drivers.

Comment: My answer was in the context of year 2018.  Please bear with me.